# Can't call parent class method from extended class

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I made `PlaceInfoAdminController` extends from `Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController`

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController;

class PlaceInfoAdminController extends CRUDController
{

    /**
    * Edit action.
    *
    * @param int|string|null $id
    *
    * @throws NotFoundHttpException If the object does not exist
    * @throws \RuntimeException     If no editable field is defined
    * @throws AccessDeniedException If access is not granted
    *
    * @return Response|RedirectResponse
    */
   public function editAction($id = null)
   {
       $request = $this->getRequest();
       // the key used to lookup the template
       $templateKey = 'edit';

       $id = $request->get($this->admin->getIdParameter());
       $existingObject = $this->admin->getObject($id);

       if (!$existingObject) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(sprintf('unable to find the object with id: %s', $id));
       }

       $this->checkParentChildAssociation($request, $existingObject); // calling parent's method
```

When I call parent class method, there comes error.

```
LogicException:
Call to undefined method Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController::checkParentChildAssociation

  at vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Controller/CRUDController.php:89
  at Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController->__call('checkParentChildAssociation', array(object(Request), object(PlaceInfo)))
     (src/Controller/PlaceInfoAdminController.php:35)
  at App\Controller\PlaceInfoAdminController->editAction('19')
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:151)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:200)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (web/app_dev.php:28)
```

Calling `checkParentChildAssociation()` of parent class from child class shows this error, but there is function `checkParentChildAssociation()` in the parent class.

What is wrong??

Comment: The exception is thrown at `CRUDController.php:89`

Comment: `checkParentChildAssociation()` is a private method

Comment: Ohhps , sorry for stupid question it is private..

Comment: However how can I override editAction....

Comment: cant you use https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/3.x/src/Controller/CRUDController.php#L1484 method in your class?

Answer (score 3):

If you're not overriding the method, you need to call it using the **parent** keyword.

```
parent::checkParentChildAssociation($request, $existingObject);
```